# Adding scripts on route config

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-routing

Upon learning [Angular Route Styles](https://github.com/tennisgent/angular-route-styles), It's easier to apply different styles on different templates.

Since it makes it so dynamic, I was wondering if there's a library to append scripts file(s) dynamically within the route configuration on a particular template like [Angular Route Styles](https://github.com/tennisgent/angular-route-styles) for stylesheet?

More like this (focusing more on **js: "app/controller/template.js"**)

```
$routeProvider.when("/",
{
  templateUrl: "template.html",
  controller: "TemplateCtrl",
  css: "css/template.css",
  js: "app/controller/template.js"
});
```

I was planning to write an external js file for the controller of the template. Thus of course, removing the property `controller: "TemplateCtrl"` on the configuration file. But this would make things more easier for code management.

Comment: TemplateCtrl is already a javascript file..

Comment: Yes. By default of using angular route, I am importing all app controllers, factories, etc. on the index page using the command `<srcipt src="js_file.js"></script>`. I was wondering if it's possible to import the core libraries on the index page and import necessary js files (with the definition above) required by the template (for its controllers, etc?